# Can compare Matcher.group(n) with String in Java?

Tags: java, matcher, string-comparison

I am trying to ping and take the ping summary to be listed out in `Matcher.group(0)`. The ping summary result which shown is:

```
Matcher.group(0)
```

```
time=35ms
time=3ms
time=2ms
time=3ms
time=2ms
time=83ms
time=3ms
time=69ms
time=2ms
time=5ms
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
```

Can I / How can I comparing these results? What I mean is, can I do something like:

```
if(m.group(0) >= "time=66ms") {
         //do something       
} else if (m.group(0) < "time=66ms") {
                 //do something
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to capture just the number of milliseconds. Where you have something like `time=\d+ms` in the regexp, use `time=(\d+)ms` instead. Then you can use `matcher.group(1)` to get that string, and use `Integer.parseInt` to get it as an int.

```
int ms = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
if (ms >= 66) {
    // do something
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Note that you don't need the `else if`, just an `else` is fine. If an int isn't `>= someValue`, then it has to to be `< someValue` -- you don't need to check that tautology in the code. By the way, I would put that number 66 into a constant somewhere:

```
private static final int TIMEOUT_THRESHOLD = 66; // or some better name
...
int ms = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
if (ms >= TIMEOUT_THRESHOLD) ...
```

That way it'll be easy to change it later, if you need to, without searching everywhere through your code.

Comment: Wow, thanks...It is educative by viewing your codes, I will try it after I change some of my code logic... Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `compare` method on the strings:

```
if (m.group(0).compare("time=66ms") >= 0)
  // do something
} else {
  //do something
}
```

You don't need the `if` in the `else` branch, though.

Comment: Thanks, but after I try to do so...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Maybe I will try to adjust my code logic, thanks...

Comment: This won't work. For instance, `time=9ms` would compare as being greater than `time=66ms` using String comparison, but you almost definitely want it to compare as being less.

Answer (score 0):

The data is in a known format:  "time" followed by "=" followed by "digits" followed by "ms"

Try this:

1. parse the string to find the millisecond value.  One regex to do this is "time=\d.ms"
2. convert the millisecond value to a number.  Consider something like this: Integer.valueOf(blam).
3. Compair the numeric valued milliseconds from the ping with some threshold value.